# 2 where conditions from 1 column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to see 2 conditional columns using the `WHERE` clause from 1 column.

For example:

I have a dataset where I have a long list of calls. I would like to see two different columns where the first column shows a count of all those calls who are equal or longer that 0 seconds and a second column that shows a count of all those calls that are equal or longer to 120 seconds.

That is my first query:

```
SELECT distinct year(date) Year,  monthname(date) as Month, count(calls) Leads
FROM database.calls
where duration >= 120
and year(date) = 2022
group by month(date)
order by max(date);
```

second query:
(The only difference it's on the 3rd line where duration is equal to 0)

```
SELECT distinct year(date) Year,  monthname(date) as Month, count(calls) Leads
FROM database.calls
where duration >= 0
and year(date) = 2022
group by month(date)
order by max(date);
```

**Expected Result**:

| Year | Month | Calls(0sec) | Calls(120sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 654 | 521 |
| 2022 | February | 895 | 465 |
| 2022 | March | 562 | 321 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For obtaining conditional sums you can use conditional aggregation: specify a condition inside your aggregate function, so that it aggregates only the eligible values.

```
SELECT YEAR(date)                    AS Year_,  
       MONTHNAME(date)               AS Month_, 
       SUM(IF(duration >   0, 1, 0)) AS Calls0Sec,
       SUM(IF(duration > 120, 1, 0)) AS Calls120Sec
FROM database.calls
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2022
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date)
ORDER BY MAX(date);
```

Note: you need to add every selected and non-aggregated field inside the `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise you can expect either DBMS errors or wrong data.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Could you please tell me what the logic is on the 3rd and 4th line where you put 0,1,0 and 120,1,0

Comment: The basic IF construct works like this: `IF (condition, if true then, if false then)`. First field is a condition, or in general any function that outputs a boolean value. If that condition evaluates to true, second field is considered, otherwise third.